# Missing headerfiles running SWUpdate on Raspberrypi 2

Tags: header-files, raspberry-pi2, swupdate

I'm trying SWUpdate out on my RaspberryPi 2 by following this [guide](https://mkrak.org/2018/01/26/updating-embedded-linux-devices-part2/) but I'm getting stuck when trying to 'make' as it from core/swupdat.c loads include/flash.h which in turn depends on libmtd.h and libubi.h.

```
~ make
 CC core/swupdate.o
In file included from core/swupdate.c:36:
include/flash.h:13:10: fatal error: libmtd.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libmtd.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated
```

These two header-files are missing on my system and can't find any information about them, so I don't know what is missing. If there some package I need to apt-get or that it is impossible to do on my old RaspberryPi.

Do anyone know what these header-files are and if can I find them in some package somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly RaspberryPi doesn't support MTD-utils. But I got in touch with the creators of SWUpdate and you can disable MTD in configuration from `make menuconfig`. Navigate to the setting `SWUpdate Settings -> General Configuration -> MTD support` and then press 'n'.

Now running `make` worked like a charm.